# Angular. How can i pass all rows from multi rows table to form? Table is inside form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to register all rows to my form.

Whole my code

```
<form name="form" novalidate  ng-cloak="" ng-submit="save()">
        <table cws-table="cwsitem" table-data="primaryProxies" table-filter='{name: filterProxy}'  table-info="settings.tableInfo"
               track-by="cwsitem.name" displayed-items="listProxies.displayedItems"
               cws-checkbox-selector
           styles="cwstable cwstable-striped cwstable-hover cwstable-bordered cwstable-block-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th cws-table-header column="select" class="col-sm-1"  cws-show="! settings.readOnly" >
                    {{data.totalSelected}}<button cws-show='showUpdateStatus(cwsitem.defaultSuperUser)'
                            cws-checkbox-all cws-checkbox-all-list="primaryProxies" cws-checkbox-displayed-items="listProxies.displayedItems"
                            cws-checkbox-displayed-selected="listProxies.displayedSelected" cws-checkbox-total-selected="listProxies.totalSelected"
                        cws-checkbox-all-display="showCheckbox"></button>
                </th>
                <th cws-table-header column="name" sortable='true' class=""><span ng-i18next="itr.table.primary_proxy"/></th>
                <th cws-table-header column="backupName" sortable='true' class=""><span ng-i18next="itr.table.backup_proxy"/></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr cws-table-body ng-class="{info: cwsitem.selected, success: cwsitem.createdProxy }">
                <td cws-show="! settings.readOnly" id="select{{$index}}">
                    <button cws-checkbox cws-checkbox-id="cwsitem" cws-checkbox-selected="cwsitem.selected" cws-checkbox-display='showUpdateStatus(cwsitem.defaultSuperUser)'></button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div
                          class="form-group "
                          cws-error
                          cws-validation
                          cws-validation-strategy
                          form = "form"
                          validation-strategy-object = "proxyValidation.updateProxyValidation"
                          back-end-errors = "backEndErrors"
                          input-name = "backupProxyname"
                          input-label = "inputBackupProxy"
                          validation-form-submit = "validTrigUpdateProxy">
                        <input class="field floatnone form-control width-output-proxy" 
                             type="text" 
                             size="3" 
                             maxlength="60" 
                             ng-model="cwsitem.name"
                             id="primary_{{$index}}"
                             name="cwsitem.sequenceNumber">
                        <p cws-error-message errors="errorMessages" class="width-error-proxy"/>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>

    </form>
```

On the other side I have a service where I have to write some strategy for validation inputs inside this form. Inputs has ng-model=cwsitem.name. This doesn`t mean that each row had the same data. I have an array of objects, where each object has property “name”.

[{"name":"proxy43.scansafe.net","port":8080,"backupName":"proxy48.scansafe.net","backupPort":8080},
                                                   {"name":"proxy137.scansafe.net","port":8080,"backupName":"","backupPort":""},
                                                   {"name":"proxy24.scansafe.net","port":8080,"backupName":"","backupPort":8080},
                                                   {"name":"proxy787.scansafe.net","port":8080,"backupName":"","backupPort":""}]

And new row takes new object of this list. 
Unfortunately when I click the button and pass this form to service, I can see that my form holds just last row and calls my strategy the same amount times as rows count. And I need my form to hold all my rows.

Comment: Can you give more details? I couldn't understand what you want to do.

Comment: Do they all have the same ngModel?

Comment: This can be engineered, however from what I can see you have a form with an input in each of the <td> is this correct? Why not wrap the table in the the <form name="form"><table><tr><td><input... pass an object to each ng-model maybe form.inputOne, form.inputTwo and then ng-submit the object?